# TRX header not found?

Tags: firmware

I want to extract firmware images and make some minor changes to it and remount is to my router via the FirmWare Modification Kit. Below you can see the errors that I get.

`# sudo ./extract_firmware.sh ~/Downloads/router_firmware_fullImage.bin ~/kamil/`

I'm getting:

```
Firmware Mod Kit (extract) v0.69 beta, (c)2010 Jeremy Collake
http://www.bitsum.com
Checking for updates ...
 You have the latest version of this kit.
LINUX system detected. Compatibility ok.
Testing file system of /home/user/kamil/ ...
Building tools ...
Build seems successful.
Preparing working directory ...
Removing any previous files ...
Creating directories ...
Extracting firmware
! untrx failed, trying splitter3
Attempting squashfs 3.0 lzma ...
Trying 'damn small' variant - used by DD-WRT v24 ...
Error: filesystem not extracted properly.
   firmware image format not compatible?
```

I'm using the latest version of the kit on ubuntu 11.04.

Additional Information:

`# cat extract.log`

```
............
untrx 0.54 beta - (c)2006-2010 Jeremy Collake

Opening /home/user/Downloads/router_firmware_fullImage.bin
read 1972267 bytes
ERROR trx header not found
splitter3 0.10 beta - (c)2010 Jeremy Collake
Opening /home/user/Downloads/router_firmware_fullImage.bin
read 1972267 bytes
SQUASHFS magic: 0x68737173
SQUASHFS version: 512.0
Found segment type 0x8 Kernel length is fecc
File system length is 1d1134
Trailer is 82b bytes
Writing /home/user/kamil//image_parts/vmlinuz
    size 65228 from offset 0 ...
SQUASHFS magic: 0x68737173
SQUASHFS version: 512.0
 ! WARNING: Unknown squashfs version.
Writing /home/user/kamil//image_parts/squashfs-lzma-image-x_x
  size 1904948 from offset 65228 ...
Writing /home/user/kamil//image_parts/hwid.txt
  size 2091 from offset 1970176 ...
Done!
```

---

Can you please help me with this problem?